# Save the layout view to SD card

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

can anyone help me, I have a project, where the project uses the barteksc library because it has to display a pdf file.
pdf has been successfully displayed in the layout, but I want the pdf file to be displayed at the same time saved to the sd card in png or jpg format

Answer (score 1):

There is a Api allows you to get a capture of a specific View, check the code below

```
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
v.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
v.destroyDrawingCache();
return b;
```